# How do I edit html/css of a specific page?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'd like to edit the link properties of a specific page so they direct elsewhere than what I specified in the social settings menu, which works globally. So, as it is now the links inherit their properties and theres no way in the cms to change this for every page. Is there a way to add it in the css? I'm not sure how to format it correctly. Here's the hmtl:

**The page id:** body.page-id-85

The HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="thb-social-home">
        <a title="Facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/">
           <span class="thb-social-icon">2</span>
        </a>
        <a title="YouTube" href="http://www.youtube.com/">
           <span class="thb-social-icon">5</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: try to add inline styles using `style="YOURSTYLES"`

Comment: You will probably have to create a custom page-template to be used for that specific page. Maybe this will help: http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

Answer (score 1):

You can use `body.page-id-85` as base selector for this page:

```
#body.page-id-85 .wrapper {
  /* wrapper specific rules*/
}

#body.page-id-85 .thb-social-home {
  /* thb-social-home rules */
}
```

Comment: This is amazing if this is possible I didn't know this :)

Comment: If it's not to much bother... how would I style the CSS? Basically how would I translate the HTML above? Thanks!!

Comment: sorry I don't quite understand what you mean.